# How Does JavaScript Calculate This Math Expression

Tags: javascript, expression

Why is the output of this expression 20?

I've tried different calculations but it always leads to the output of 24.

Could some please explain to me how Javascript calculates this expression?

Thank You.

```js
let A = 2;
let B = 4;
let result = B + B * A + 8;

console.log(result);
```

`Output: 20`

Comment: `4 + 4 * 2 + 8` = `4 + (4 * 2) + 8` = `4 + 8 + 8` = `20` -- I'm not sure what you expected. It's just basic maths...

Comment: If you use a simple calculator, punching in one operation at a time, you're doing `((B + B) * A) + 8`. When you carry out that calculation *all at once*, it's `B + (B * A) + 8`. This isn't limited to JavaScript, or even programming; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations.

Comment: Hi Scott, you can look here of operation order https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Maybe you wanted to do `let result = (B + B) * A + 8`, take a look at what jon commented, the order of operations really matter in programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps to understand

```js
let A = 2;
let B = 4;
let result = (B + B) * A + 8;

console.log(result); //Outputs 24

A = 2;
B = 4;
result = B + (B * A) + 8;

console.log(result); //Outputs 20
```

Answer (score 1):

It's evaluating like this:

result = `4 + 4 * 2 + 8`

Because of point before line calculation, a parenthesis is placed around the multiplication.

Like this: `4 + (4 * 2) + 8`

Which evaluates to `4 + 8 + 8`, and you can't that's 20.

Maybe your calculator didn't do point before line calculation.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It follows the rule of PEMDAS (which stands for Parathesis, Exponents, Multiplication and Division, Addition and Subtraction).

What this simply means is that multiplication and division has a "higher" order than addition or subtraction. Which means multiplication and division will take place first before any addition or subtraction.

Comment: In the example, the `B * A` operation will happen first because it take precedence over the addition operations in the equation.